# Does page.php need the loop?

Tags: loop, templates

Simple question. Does page.php need the loop? The Loop 'loops' through several pages/posts/content. However the page.php template only has 1 page. There's nothing to loop through. I noticed that simple functions such as the_title() and the_content() work outside the loop inside page.php. So...

Does page.php need the loop?

If so, why?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the link. Feel free to delete this question